# Solving 2D Poisson equation with Dirichlet boundary conditions in Python

Tags: python, numerics, poisson

I am trying to solve the following PDE:

$$
    \begin{align*}
    u_{xx} + u_{yy}
    =
    \begin{cases}
    - \cos(x) \quad -\pi/2 \leq x \leq \pi/2, \\
    0 \quad \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
    \end{align*}
$$
The domain is the rectangle with vertices $(-π, 0), (-π,2), (π,0)$ and $(π,2)$. The boundary conditions are Dirichlet: $u$ must be zero on the boundary.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import diags, csr_matrix
from scipy.sparse.linalg import spsolve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

x_min = -np.pi #Left endpoint of x interval
x_max = np.pi  #Right endpoint of x interval
y_min = 0      #Left endpoint of y interval
y_max = 2      #Right endpoint of y interval

#mesh sizes and grid points
dx = 0.05                       
dy = 0.01                       
nx = int((x_max - x_min)/dx)-1 
ny = int((y_max - y_min)/dy)-1
n = nx*ny
x = np.linspace(x_min+dx, x_max-dx, nx)  # Grid points in x-direction
y = np.linspace(y_min+dy, y_max-dy, ny)  # Grid points in y-direction
xg, yg = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# Create the diagonals
ones = np.full(n, 1)

a=np.ones(ny,dtype='float')
b=np.array([0.0],dtype='float')
c=np.concatenate((a,b),axis=0)
lower_diagonal = np.tile(c,nx)
upper_diagonal = np.tile(c,nx)


# Create the offsets
offsets = [0, -1, 1,ny,-ny]

# Create the sparse matrix
A = diags([-2*ones/dx**2 + -2*ones/dy**2,lower_diagonal/dy**2,upper_diagonal/dy**2,ones/dx**2,ones/dx**2], offsets, shape=(n, n), dtype=float)

# Construct the RHS
b = np.zeros((ny,nx))

for i in range(nx):
    
    if abs(x[i]) <= np.pi/2:
        
        b[:, i] = -np.cos( x[i] )
        
b1 = b.reshape(n,1)

#Solve the linear system using a sparse matrix solver
As = csr_matrix(A)
bs = csr_matrix(b1)
u = spsolve(As, bs).reshape(ny, nx)

#Plot the solution
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
surf = ax.plot_surface(xg, yg, u)
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('u');
```

Here is what my solution looks like:

[image: my solution]

Here's the correct solution:

[image: correct solution]

However, I can't figure out where my code is wrong. The only non-trivial thing I have done is generated the matrix `A` using scipy. I think my matrix is correct, though. :/ With `dx = 1.2 (nx = 4), dy = 0.4 (ny = 4)`, my matrix is of the following form:

[image: matrix]

I think this is correct, no?

Comment: I believe your matrix is incorrect. The blocks along the diagonal should all be the same for these boundary conditions but the last block in your matrix has zeros at the end of the off-diagonals where there should be ones. The last row of the matrix is saying that the 4-point stencil at the final node only overlaps one other node. That can't be right.